# MSSQL Split datetime range into lines separated at 05:00 o'clock

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a interval (`2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 ----  2013-12-05 07:06:34.000`)

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(line varchar(3),from_date DATETIME, to_date DATETIME);

INSERT @d VALUES ('G01','20131125 04:05:27','20131205 07:06:34');
```

I want to split into lines per day.
My day starts at 05:00 o'clock instead of 00:00.

the result should be like:

```
G01 ----  2013-11-25 04:05:27.00 ----  2013-11-25 04:59:59.00
G01 ----  2013-11-25 05:00:00.00 ----     2013-11-26 04:59:59.00
G01 ----  2013-11-26 05:00:00.00 ----     2013-11-27 04:59:59.00
.
.
.
G01 ----  2013-12-05 05:00:00.00 ----     2013-12-05 07:06:34.00
```

Comment: Construct a calendar table (either real or a tally) and join it with your data

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[datestable] (
    @DateStart datetime,
    @DateEnd datetime
)
RETURNS @datestable TABLE 
(
    dStart datetime NULL, 
    dEnd datetime NULL
)
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @time time = '04:59:59.000',
            @s int, @e int, @r int

    DECLARE @dates TABLE (
        d datetime
    )

    DECLARE @ddates TABLE (
        dstart datetime,
        dend datetime,
        rn int
    )

    SELECT  @s = CASE WHEN CAST(@DateStart as time) < @time THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,
            @e = CASE WHEN CAST(@DateEnd as time) < @time THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT CAST(@DateStart as date) as d
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day,1,d) as date) 
        FROM cte
        WHERE d < CAST(@DateEnd as date)
    )

    INSERT INTO @dates
    SELECT d
    FROM cte

    IF @s != @e AND CAST(@DateStart as date) = CAST(@DateEnd as date)
    BEGIN
        -- Here we go if dates are equal and start/end time are start<4:59:59 and end>4:59:59 
        INSERT INTO @datestable
        SELECT  @DateStart as dstart,
                CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@DateStart,20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) as dend
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@DateStart,20) + ' 05:00:00.000' as datetime),
                @DateEnd
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN


        IF @s = 1 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ddates
            SELECT  d.d as dstart,
                    d1.d as dend,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.d) as rn
            FROM @dates d
            LEFT JOIN @dates d1
                ON d.d = d1.d

            SELECT @r = @@ROWCOUNT

                IF @e = 1 and @r > 1
                BEGIN
                    --Here goes if both times < 4:59:59
                    INSERT INTO @datestable
                    SELECT  CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN @DateStart ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dstart,20) + ' 05:00:00.000' as datetime) END as dstart,
                            CASE WHEN rn = @r-1 THEN @DateEnd ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dend,20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) END as dEnd
                    FROM @ddates d
                    WHERE rn < @r

                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --Here goes if  start time < 4:59:59 and end time > 4:59:59
                    INSERT INTO @datestable
                    SELECT  CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN @DateStart ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dstart,20) + ' 05:00:00.000' as datetime) END as dstart,
                            CASE WHEN rn = @r THEN @DateEnd ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dend,20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) END as dEnd
                    FROM @ddates d
                END
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ddates
            SELECT  d.d as dstart,
                    d1.d as dend,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.d) as rn
            FROM @dates d
            LEFT JOIN @dates d1
                ON d.d = DATEADD(day,-1,d1.d)

            SELECT @r = @@ROWCOUNT

                IF @e = 1 and @r > 1
                BEGIN
                    --Here we go if start time > 4:59:59 and end time < 4:59:59
                    INSERT INTO @datestable
                    SELECT  CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN @DateStart ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dstart,20) + ' 05:00:00.000' as datetime) END as dstart,
                            CASE WHEN rn = @r-1 THEN @DateEnd ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dend,20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) END as dEnd
                    FROM @ddates d
                    WHERE rn < @r
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    ----Here goes if both times > 4:59:59
                    INSERT INTO @datestable
                    SELECT  CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN @DateStart ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dstart,20) + ' 05:00:00.000' as datetime) END as dstart,
                            CASE WHEN rn = @r THEN @DateEnd ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),d.dend,20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) END as dEnd
                    FROM @ddates d
                END
        END

    END;

    RETURN;
END;
```

Then:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(line nvarchar(3), from_date DATETIME, to_date DATETIME);

INSERT @d VALUES 
--Here dates are different (few days)
('G01', '2013-11-25 04:05:27.000','2013-11-28 04:06:34.000'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
('G02', '2012-11-21 14:11:09.220','2012-11-23 14:48:28.733'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G03', '2016-05-18 03:00:00.000','2016-05-20 07:00:00.000'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G04', '2013-11-25 05:05:27.000','2013-11-27 04:06:34.000'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
--Here dates are equal
('G05', '2013-11-25 04:05:27.000','2013-11-25 04:06:34.000'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
('G06', '2014-01-02 23:24:07.120','2014-01-02 23:25:28.130'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G07', '2014-01-02 02:24:07.120','2014-01-02 23:25:28.130'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
--Here dates are different (1 day)
('G08', '2014-01-02 23:24:07.120 ','2014-01-03 00:25:28.130'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G09', '2014-01-02 04:24:07.120 ','2014-01-03 00:25:28.130'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
('G10', '2014-01-02 04:24:07.120 ','2014-01-03 06:25:28.130')--date start < 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00

SELECT  d.line,
        dt.dStart,
        dt.dEnd
FROM @d d
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[datestable] (d.from_date, d.to_date) as dt
```

Output:

```
line dStart                     dEnd
G01  2013-11-25 04:05:27.000    2013-11-25 04:59:59.000
G01  2013-11-26 05:00:00.000    2013-11-26 04:59:59.000
G01  2013-11-27 05:00:00.000    2013-11-28 04:06:34.000
G02  2012-11-21 14:11:09.220    2012-11-22 04:59:59.000
G02  2012-11-22 05:00:00.000    2012-11-23 04:59:59.000
G02  2012-11-23 05:00:00.000    2012-11-23 14:48:28.733
G03  2016-05-18 03:00:00.000    2016-05-18 04:59:59.000
G03  2016-05-19 05:00:00.000    2016-05-19 04:59:59.000
G03  2016-05-20 05:00:00.000    2016-05-20 07:00:00.000
G04  2013-11-25 05:05:27.000    2013-11-26 04:59:59.000
G04  2013-11-26 05:00:00.000    2013-11-27 04:06:34.000
G05  2013-11-25 04:05:27.000    2013-11-25 04:06:34.000
G06  2014-01-02 23:24:07.120    2014-01-02 23:25:28.130
G07  2014-01-02 02:24:07.120    2014-01-02 04:59:59.000
G07  2014-01-02 05:00:00.000    2014-01-02 23:25:28.130
G08  2014-01-02 23:24:07.120    2014-01-03 00:25:28.130
G09  2014-01-02 04:24:07.120    2014-01-03 00:25:28.130
G10  2014-01-02 04:24:07.120    2014-01-02 04:59:59.000
G10  2014-01-03 05:00:00.000    2014-01-03 06:25:28.130
```

Last query you can put into view.

**EDIT: 2021-05-12**

New variant is to use `cte` with some logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT line,
       from_date,
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, from_date) < 5 AND CAST(from_date as date) != CAST(to_date as date)
                THEN CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),from_date,20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime)
            WHEN CAST(from_date as date) = CAST(to_date as date) OR DATEPART(hour, to_date) < 5 AND DATEDIFF(day,from_date,to_date) <=1
                THEN to_date
            ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),DATEADD(day,1,from_date),20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) END as new_to_date,
       to_date
FROM #dates
UNION ALL 
SELECT line,
       CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),new_to_date,20) + ' 05:00:00.000' as datetime),
       CASE WHEN CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),DATEADD(day,1,new_to_date),20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) > to_date
                THEN to_date 
            ELSE CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),DATEADD(day,1,new_to_date),20) + ' 04:59:59.000' as datetime) END,
       to_date
FROM cte
WHERE to_date > new_to_date
)

SELECT line,
       from_date,
       new_to_date as to_date
FROM cte 
ORDER BY line, from_date
```

Output will be:

```
line    from_date                to_date

G01     2013-11-25 04:05:27.000  2013-11-25 04:59:59.000
G01     2013-11-25 05:00:00.000  2013-11-26 04:59:59.000
G01     2013-11-26 05:00:00.000  2013-11-27 04:59:59.000
G01     2013-11-27 05:00:00.000  2013-11-28 04:06:34.000

G02     2012-11-21 14:11:09.220  2012-11-22 04:59:59.000
G02     2012-11-22 05:00:00.000  2012-11-23 04:59:59.000
G02     2012-11-23 05:00:00.000  2012-11-23 14:48:28.733

G03     2016-05-18 03:00:00.000  2016-05-18 04:59:59.000
G03     2016-05-18 05:00:00.000  2016-05-19 04:59:59.000
G03     2016-05-19 05:00:00.000  2016-05-20 04:59:59.000
G03     2016-05-20 05:00:00.000  2016-05-20 07:00:00.000

G04     2013-11-25 05:05:27.000  2013-11-26 04:59:59.000
G04     2013-11-26 05:00:00.000  2013-11-27 04:06:34.000

G05     2013-11-25 04:05:27.000  2013-11-25 04:06:34.000

G06     2014-01-02 23:24:07.120  2014-01-02 23:25:28.130

G07     2014-01-02 02:24:07.120  2014-01-02 23:25:28.130

G08     2014-01-02 23:24:07.120  2014-01-03 00:25:28.130

G09     2014-01-02 04:24:07.120  2014-01-02 04:59:59.000
G09     2014-01-02 05:00:00.000  2014-01-03 00:25:28.130

G10     2014-01-02 04:24:07.120  2014-01-02 04:59:59.000
G10     2014-01-02 05:00:00.000  2014-01-03 04:59:59.000
G10     2014-01-03 05:00:00.000  2014-01-03 06:25:28.130
```

Comment: Thanks, but my table consists of many intervals. Could it be a view with my table as source instead?

Comment: I recommend you to put this in table-valued function. And cross apply you table with it.

Comment: Ok, this is good. To simplify the question, i did not mention that i have a varchar fields together with the two dates. I have tried to update the function with the field with no success.

Comment: I edited the post one more time to answer your comment.

Comment: Arh it dos not work when i use theese two datetimes:

INSERT @d VALUES ('G01', '2012-11-21 14:11:09.220','2012-11-21 14:48:28.733');

It generates two lines, even though the interval is not crossing 05:00 o'clock.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please, next time when asking a question provide more samples of data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for accepting. I just realized one more situation may occur. What should be outputed if you pass same dates but like this '2016-05-18 03:00:00.000' and '2016-05-18 07:00:00.000'? As I understand function must return 2 rows first 2016-05-18 03:00:00.000 and 2016-05-18 04:59:59.000 and second 2016-05-18 05:00:00.000 and 2016-05-18 07:00:00.000. Am I right? If so I will change my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right in your asumption. Also there is another problem. These two dates INSERT @d VALUES ('G01', '2014-01-02 23:24:07.120 ','2014-01-03 00:25:28.130'); The End date is being traformed to 2. jan instead of 3. jan.

Comment: Wow, you're really working on this. Thanks man. Let me double check, but for now it looks like all cases are solved.

Comment: Hey, yes now i have implemented the solution. It works perfectly :) Thanks so much for your help. This really was a hard one for me.

Comment: Hi again. After 5 years we are still using this solution, but there are some issues, that i haven't been able to resolve in the example i am missing a row number 2. I did not see this earlier. It should be

**G01  2013-11-25 05:00:00.000    2013-11-26 04:59:59.000**

Comment: Hi @gofr1 i really appreciate. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @Iballan Sorry for untimely response! I add another solution, please give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will help you.

```
declare @start datetime='2013-11-25 04:05:27.000' 
,@dateend datetime = '2013-12-05 07:06:34.000' --set range

;with tm as ( -- generate and populate table 
select @start dt, 1 evt
union all
select dateadd(minute,67,tm.dt), evt+1
from tm where dt <=@dateend
)
,shifted as ( -- shift and combine
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cast(dateadd(hour,-5,tm.dt) as char(10)) order by tm.dt) rn,
convert(char(10), dateadd(hour,-5,tm.dt),101 ) s,
tm.*
from tm
)
select * from shifted
order by dt
option (maxrecursion 1000)--required because tm has >100 rows
```

Some results. Note that next range starts at 5:00.

```
rn  s           dt                      evt
1   11/24/2013  2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 1
1   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 05:12:27.000 2
2   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 06:19:27.000 3
3   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 07:26:27.000 4
4   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 08:33:27.000 5
5   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 09:40:27.000 6
6   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 10:47:27.000 7
7   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 11:54:27.000 8
8   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 13:01:27.000 9
9   11/25/2013  2013-11-25 14:08:27.000 10
10  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 15:15:27.000 11
11  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 16:22:27.000 12
12  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 17:29:27.000 13
13  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 18:36:27.000 14
14  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 19:43:27.000 15
15  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 20:50:27.000 16
16  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 21:57:27.000 17
17  11/25/2013  2013-11-25 23:04:27.000 18
18  11/25/2013  2013-11-26 00:11:27.000 19
19  11/25/2013  2013-11-26 01:18:27.000 20
20  11/25/2013  2013-11-26 02:25:27.000 21
21  11/25/2013  2013-11-26 03:32:27.000 22
22  11/25/2013  2013-11-26 04:39:27.000 23
1   11/26/2013  2013-11-26 05:46:27.000 24
2   11/26/2013  2013-11-26 06:53:27.000 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Iballan's comment to gofr1's answer that a record would go missing in some cases.

This happens because the CTE creates only enough rows to satisfy 1 row per date - but in some cases there should be multiple for a single date. E.g. if an input range starts before the cutoff time part, it should have two records for that date.

I have written another function to accomplish this.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [dbo].[datestable]
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[datestable] (
    @DateStart datetime2(3),
    @DateEnd datetime2(3)
)
RETURNS @DatesTable TABLE 
(
    dStart datetime2(3) NULL, 
    dEnd datetime2(3) NULL
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EndTimeCutoff time(3) = '04:59:59.999'
    DECLARE @StartTimeCutoff time(3) = dateadd(ms,1,@EndTimeCutoff)
    DECLARE @EndTimeCutoffChar char(12) = convert(char(12),@EndTimeCutoff,14)
            ,@StartTimeCutoffChar char(12) = convert(char(12),@StartTimeCutoff,14)

    IF @DateEnd>=@DateStart -- if a period is required for a stop that starts and ends at the same time use ">=" - if not then use ">"
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @EndTime datetime2(3) -- endtime for iterating periods
                ,@StartTime datetime2(3) -- starttime for iterating periods
                ,@TmpEndTime datetime2(3)
                ,@FullDays integer

        SELECT @StartTime=@DateStart, @EndTime=@DateEnd
        -- create the first interval from time part of @DateStart until next @endtimecutoff
        IF cast(@DateStart as time(3))<=@EndTimeCutoff -- the first period is starting before the cutoff so the first period must end either at cutoff or end - whichever comes first
        BEGIN
            SELECT @TmpEndTime = convert(char(8),@StartTime,112) + ' '+@EndTimeCutoffChar -- endtime for the first day
            IF @DateEnd>@TmpEndTime -- period ends after cutoff of first day - create 1 period from start to the cutoff of first day
                SELECT @EndTime=@TmpEndTime
            ELSE
                SELECT @EndTime=@DateEnd
        END
        ELSE -- first period starts after the cutoff - create 1 period from start to the first ocurring time of either dateend or the next day's cutoff
        BEGIN
            SELECT @TmpEndTime = convert(char(8),dateadd(day,1,@StartTime),112) + ' '+@EndTimeCutoffChar -- cutoff endtime for the next day
            IF @DateEnd>@TmpEndTime -- period ends after cutoff of second day - create 1 period from start to the cutoff of second day
                SELECT @EndTime=@TmpEndTime
            ELSE
                SELECT @EndTime=@DateEnd
        END
        INSERT INTO @DatesTable (dStart,dEnd) values (@StartTime,@EndTime) -- insertion of first period range

        SELECT @FullDays = floor(datediff_big(ms,@EndTime,@DateEnd)/(24*60*60*1000)) -- full days remaining
                , @StartTime = convert(CHAR(8),@EndTime,112)+' '+@StartTimeCutoffChar -- set new starttime

        IF @FullDays>0 -- add the full day periods from @starttimecutoff to @endtimecutoff
        BEGIN
            WITH CTE AS (SELECT 0 AS "rn" UNION ALL SELECT rn+1 FROM CTE WHERE rn<@FullDays-1)
            INSERT INTO @DatesTable(dStart,dEnd)
            SELECT dateadd(day,rn,@StartTime), dateadd(DAY,rn+1,@EndTime) FROM CTE
        END

        SELECT @EndTime=(SELECT MAX(dEND) FROM @DatesTable)
        SELECT @StartTime=convert(char(8),@EndTime,112)+' '+@StartTimeCutoffChar
        IF @StartTime<=@DateEnd AND @DateEnd<>@DateStart -- create period for the remaining time (part of day) of the period
                                                        -- period is already created above for the case where @DateEnd=@DateStart
                    -- if a period is required for a stop that starts and ends at the same time on the "@starttimecutoff" exactly then use "<=" 
                    -- if not then use "<"
            INSERT INTO @DatesTable(dStart,dEnd) VALUES (@StartTime,@DateEnd)
    END;

    RETURN;
END
```

Adding a few data points to the table to retrieve data from gofr1's answer above.

```
    DECLARE @d TABLE(line nvarchar(3), from_date DATETIME, to_date DATETIME, stopid int identity(1,1));

INSERT @d VALUES 
--Here dates are different (few days)
('G01', '2013-11-25 04:05:27.000','2013-11-28 04:06:34.000'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
('G02', '2012-11-21 14:11:09.220','2012-11-23 14:48:28.733'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G03', '2016-05-18 03:00:00.000','2016-05-20 07:00:00.000'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G04', '2013-11-25 05:05:27.000','2013-11-27 04:06:34.000'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
--Here dates are equal
('G05', '2013-11-25 04:05:27.000','2013-11-25 04:06:34.000'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
('G06', '2014-01-02 23:24:07.120','2014-01-02 23:25:28.130'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G07', '2014-01-02 02:24:07.120','2014-01-02 23:25:28.130'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
--Here dates are different (1 day)
('G08', '2014-01-02 23:24:07.120','2014-01-03 00:25:28.130'),--date start > 5:00:00 and date end > 5:00:00
('G09', '2014-01-02 04:24:07.120','2014-01-03 00:25:28.130'),--date start < 5:00:00 and date end < 5:00:00
-- Here dates are exactly on datetime cutoffs
('G10', '2020-01-02 04:59:59.999','2020-01-03 04:59:59.999'),--date start = cutoff and date end = cutoff
('G10', '2020-01-05 05:00:00.000','2020-01-05 05:00:00.000')--date start = cutoff start = date end

SELECT  d.line,
        d.stopid,
        row_number() over (partition by d.stopid order by dt.dstart asc) as "stopid_split",
        d.from_date as "stop_from_date",
        d.to_date as "stop_end_date",
        dt.dStart as "split_start_date",
        dt.dEnd as "split_end_date"
FROM @d d
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[datestable] (d.from_date, d.to_date) as dt
```

With the output here (my apologies for the format - my skills are not good enough).

```
    line    stopid  stopid_split    stop_from_date  stop_end_date   split_start_date    split_end_date
G01 1   1   2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 2013-11-28 04:06:34.000 2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 2013-11-25 04:59:59.999
G01 1   2   2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 2013-11-28 04:06:34.000 2013-11-25 05:00:00.000 2013-11-26 04:59:59.999
G01 1   3   2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 2013-11-28 04:06:34.000 2013-11-26 05:00:00.000 2013-11-27 04:59:59.999
G01 1   4   2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 2013-11-28 04:06:34.000 2013-11-27 05:00:00.000 2013-11-28 04:06:34.000
G02 2   1   2012-11-21 14:11:09.220 2012-11-23 14:48:28.733 2012-11-21 14:11:09.220 2012-11-22 04:59:59.999
G02 2   2   2012-11-21 14:11:09.220 2012-11-23 14:48:28.733 2012-11-22 05:00:00.000 2012-11-23 04:59:59.999
G02 2   3   2012-11-21 14:11:09.220 2012-11-23 14:48:28.733 2012-11-23 05:00:00.000 2012-11-23 14:48:28.733
G03 3   1   2016-05-18 03:00:00.000 2016-05-20 07:00:00.000 2016-05-18 03:00:00.000 2016-05-18 04:59:59.999
G03 3   2   2016-05-18 03:00:00.000 2016-05-20 07:00:00.000 2016-05-18 05:00:00.000 2016-05-19 04:59:59.999
G03 3   3   2016-05-18 03:00:00.000 2016-05-20 07:00:00.000 2016-05-19 05:00:00.000 2016-05-20 04:59:59.999
G03 3   4   2016-05-18 03:00:00.000 2016-05-20 07:00:00.000 2016-05-20 05:00:00.000 2016-05-20 07:00:00.000
G04 4   1   2013-11-25 05:05:27.000 2013-11-27 04:06:34.000 2013-11-25 05:05:27.000 2013-11-26 04:59:59.999
G04 4   2   2013-11-25 05:05:27.000 2013-11-27 04:06:34.000 2013-11-26 05:00:00.000 2013-11-27 04:06:34.000
G05 5   1   2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 2013-11-25 04:06:34.000 2013-11-25 04:05:27.000 2013-11-25 04:06:34.000
G06 6   1   2014-01-02 23:24:07.120 2014-01-02 23:25:28.130 2014-01-02 05:00:00.000 2014-01-02 23:25:28.130
G06 6   2   2014-01-02 23:24:07.120 2014-01-02 23:25:28.130 2014-01-02 23:24:07.120 2014-01-02 23:25:28.130
G07 7   1   2014-01-02 02:24:07.120 2014-01-02 23:25:28.130 2014-01-02 02:24:07.120 2014-01-02 04:59:59.999
G07 7   2   2014-01-02 02:24:07.120 2014-01-02 23:25:28.130 2014-01-02 05:00:00.000 2014-01-02 23:25:28.130
G08 8   1   2014-01-02 23:24:07.120 2014-01-03 00:25:28.130 2014-01-02 23:24:07.120 2014-01-03 00:25:28.130
G09 9   1   2014-01-02 04:24:07.120 2014-01-03 00:25:28.130 2014-01-02 04:24:07.120 2014-01-02 04:59:59.999
G09 9   2   2014-01-02 04:24:07.120 2014-01-03 00:25:28.130 2014-01-02 05:00:00.000 2014-01-03 00:25:28.130
G10 10  1   2020-01-02 05:00:00.000 2020-01-03 05:00:00.000 2020-01-02 05:00:00.000 2020-01-03 04:59:59.999
G10 10  2   2020-01-02 05:00:00.000 2020-01-03 05:00:00.000 2020-01-03 05:00:00.000 2020-01-03 05:00:00.000
G10 11  1   2020-01-05 05:00:00.000 2020-01-05 05:00:00.000 2020-01-05 05:00:00.000 2020-01-05 05:00:00.000
```